# PyCharm: displaying useful information as the terminal name

Tags: pycharm

I am using PyCharm and its integrated terminal to run development scripts like `make`, `bash` and different folders. I have several terminal tabs open, in different paths and running different batch jobs.

Is it possible to make PyCharm to display anything useful as the terminal name, like process name or path, instead of "Local", "Local (2)", etc. Because this makes navigating terminals difficult.

[image]

Other terminal software, like iTerm for Mac, automatically pick up this information from the shell. Does PyCharm integrated terminal support such integrations with UNIX shells?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not available in IntelliJ-based IDEs at the moment. Feel free to follow [IDEA-174678](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-174678) & [IDEA-183042](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-183042).

Answer (score 1):

Right-click the tab and choose [Rename Session](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/terminal-emulator.html#configure-the-terminal-emulator)

Comment: Thank you! Also clarified my question with another point.